# How can I show only certain movies in iTunes on the Apple TV 2nd Generation?

Tags: itunes, appletv, home-sharing

When I connect my Apple TV 2nd Generation to my iTunes home sharing account I see all Movies, Music etc. I can choose which photos to show, however.

I would like to be able to choose which Movies and Music to show on the Apple TV (and on other connected computers) and which not.

All Movies and Music were bought with the same Apple ID (which is also used for sharing).

Comment: Have you tried unticking the items you don't want shown on the Apple TV?

Comment: Yes, it also shows the unticked movies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, everything in iTunes is shared via Home Sharing.  Photos are the only part of Home Sharing that offer any choices.

Remove undesired movies, etc, from iTunes if you don't want other devices to have access too.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Preferences>Sharing>Share my library on local network / Share selected playlists]

It's not Home Sharing, but this allows you to share over Bonjour, and you can drag just the movies you want into their own playlist.